# Flutter Driver Test Coverage Report

Tags: flutter, code-coverage, test-coverage, flutter-test

Is there a way to generate **the coverage report** from

```
flutter drive --target=test_driver/file.dart
```

??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it is not currently possible, and probably never will be:

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/7474.

Furthermore, the Flutter team is moving away from flutter_driver in favor of augmenting flutter_test to work on devices, because flutter_driver is hard to embed in CI toolchains. As a result, many flutter developers opt to use Widget tests instead (which *do* support coverage, to be sure).